# Pointers in C, returning from functions?

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to create a simple matrix multiplication program in C. 
To do this I have opted to use 2 functions: 1 to simply create matrices, and 1 to hold all the created matrices (for doing multiplication).

I have finally managed to work out how to pass an array from a function (or more specifically pass a pointer to the array from a function), however, I want the function matrixWelcome() below to be passed the number of rows & columns of the array. This is where I am stuck.

Currently gcc is giving me error invalid type argument of ‘unary *’ for line -> rows = *i;

My code is:

```
void matrixWelcome() {
    int selection;
    int a, b, c, d, *rows, *columns;
    int *matrix1[0][0], *matrix2[0][0];

    printf("Welcome to matrix mode\n");
    printf("Please select from the following: \n");
    printf("1 - Matrix multiplication");

    scanf("%d", &selection);

    switch (selection) {
        case 1:
            printf("Selected matrix multiplication...\n");
            printf("Please enter matrix 1\n");

            matrix1[*rows][*columns] = matrixInput(*rows, *columns);
            printf("%d\n", *matrix1[1][1]);
            a = *rows;
            b = *columns;

            printf("****ROWS = %d, COLUMNS = %d", a, b);

           // printf("Matrix 1 has %d rows and %d columns", rows, columns);
            printf("Please enter matrix 2\n");
           // matrix2 = matrixInput();
            break;

        default:
            printf("No input entered\n");
            break;
    }
}

int *matrixInput(int *rows, int *columns) {
    int i, j, x, y;
    int *array_pointer = malloc(5 * sizeof(int)); //grab some memory

    if (array_pointer == NULL) { // check that we have successfully got memory
        return NULL;
    }

    // Number of rows & columns for matrix 1
    printf("Enter number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    printf("\nEnter number of columns: ");
    scanf("%d", &j);

    rows = *i;
    columns = *j;

    // Initialise 2D array to hold values
    int matrix_input[i][j];

    printf("Enter values for matrix, starting at 1,1 and moving across 1st row; then move across 2nd row etc..");

    // loop to store values in matrix
    for (x=0; x<i; x++) {
        for (y=0; y<j; y++) {

            int value_entered;
            scanf("%d", &value_entered);
            matrix_input[x][y] = value_entered; 


        }
    }

    *array_pointer = matrix_input[i][j]; 

    // print out matrix - just to confirm
    printf("You've entered the following matrix: \n");
    for (x=0; x<i; x++) {
        for (y=0; y<j; y++) {
            printf("%4d", matrix_input[x][y]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return array_pointer;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: w.r.t. the title: remember, a pointer to an object is only valid for that objects lifetime. (e.g. a pointer to an array declared in a function is invalid once the function returns.)

Answer (score 3):

`i` is an `int`.  You don't need to dereference it.  You do need to dereference `rows`, though - `*rows = i` will work just fine.  Don't dereference when calling your function, though.  Use:

```
 matrixInput(rows, columns);
```

since you want to pass the pointers.

Comment: More specifically, you _can't_ dereference an int.  It doesn't make any conceptual sense.

Comment: Thanks for the help it is greatly appreciated. When you say you don't dereference ints, how come you go on to dereference rows '*rows = i' ?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, that was silly. I am now getting a segmentation error: 11 when I run the program (compiles without any errors or warnings). Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: You haven't allocated any space for `rows` or `columns`.

Answer (score 2):

```
int *matrix1[0][0], *matrix2[0][0];
```

this is strange and incorrect (you should not declare global variables as 0-dimensionned arrays).

And your code is not complete. You forgot at least the `#include <stdio.h>` and also `#include <stdlib.h>`

And your code don't compile.

You should try to compile with all warnings enabled, e.g. on Linux with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) with

```
gcc -Wall -g cud.c -o cud
```

I'm getting 4 errors and more than 10 warnings.

Don't post a code till you've got no warnings and no more errors. Edit & improve your code till all errors and warning are gone. Then debug your code (with a debugger, like `gdb` on Linux).

Comment: A canonical example of a function returning pointers is simply `malloc` (and it is often fully coded in C, above lower level system calls like `mmap`)

Comment: Sorry - forgot to mention that this was only part of the code. I had a lot of other code which included the libraries etc. Thanks for the help though :)